# How to export a project in Redmine

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I couldn't find any option to export a project in Redmine control panel. Is there any way to create a tarball of a project so that one can view it later on browser? I need this to deliver the project to a customer.

PS I use the Bitnami Redmine Stack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can export your whole Redmine installation (that is the database, uploaded files, ...) and ship it to the customer as described by Jota Martos in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62699804/421705).

However, with that approach, you would ship all data contained in the Redmine to your customer, including unrelated projects and potentially private data. Also, the data is not really browsable on its own.

With that being said, there is no built-in way to export entire projects in Redmine, partly because with global data (such as users, trackers, issue statuses,, shared versions, cross-project relations, ...) it's not clear what exactly belongs to this project, partly also because a later import of the exported files are even harder.

Still, there are ways in Redmine to export data in human-readable form:

- For wikis, you can find an export option on one of the index pages linked in the sidebar. There, you can find an **Also available as: HTML** link at the bottom to export the entire wiki.
- Issues can be exported as PDF files (including all history) by clicking on **Also available as: PDF** on an individual issue or issue lists. Alternatively, you can also export the current fields of multiple issues as a CSV file (without the history).

Note that there are limits of how many issues can be exported at once and that it might take a long time to create the files. Depending on your setup, this might result in timeouts of your webserver. You might also try to use the [Redmine API](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api) to gather the necessary data.

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can stop the services and create a .tar.gz file with the entire installation directory. You can share that file with the customer later so he/she only needs to uncompress the file into the same folder you used to install the stack. You can learn more about this here:

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/administration/backup-restore/

In case you have a Mac OS X VM, you will need to access the VM and compress the /opt/bitnami folder. The customer will need to deploy the OS X VM and replace the /opt/bitnami directory with the one you provide.

Happy to help.